# db2 resource limitation error while using ibm-db

Tags: db2

I have a generic question (not an issue). I am trying to run a big query with (lot of join conditions connecting 15-20 tables). Do we have any limitations in ibm_db while running big queries ? The query has been running in our production environment for more than 15 years. I am able to run the query in a in-home .Net tool. However, while running it using ibm-db in pycharm I keep getting sqlcode -905 resource limitation error. Is there anything I am missing with ibm-db usage ?

Any insight will be helpful. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this -905 sqlcode has nothing to do with python or ibm_db.

Instead, it is more likely due to how the workload/resource management is configured at the Db2 server. Your question gave zero facts about the target Db2 environment, or about the difference(s) between the execution that works (.net) versus the execution that triggers the limitation.

One specific detail to eliminate is that the account (auth-id) used for the .net application might be different to the account you use when connecting from python. The Db2-server may be configured to allocate based on User-Id (auth-ID) , or other client side factor (depending on the Db2-server platform and version).

You can prove that the -905 symptom has nothing to do with python or ibm_db by temporary eliminating both, for example by submitting the same query from the db2cli tool (or db2 clp if your client workstation has it), or by submitting the query from jdbc (as long as you use the same account name for connecting as you do with python).

Contact your DBA team for details of the configuration of the WLM or RLF or whatever resource management tooling is deployed at the target Db2 subsystem. In addition, use python ibm_db to print out the full details of the exception (including the resource name, limit amount1/2, limit source, as they can also yield more information).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It was indeed a resource issue. The server was configured to allocate based on the auth ID. I had the resources bumped.